# Google Play Console: Can we use different application id for internal, closed, open testing and final release

Tags: android

I am new to Google Play Console for Android development and would like to ask if we can upload aab files with different application id for internal, closed, open testing and final release. I tried to find an official document but could not find any.

For Apple, it seems like we can use different bundle id for different test in TestFlight so would like to ask about Android.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't.

Why would you need this, anyway?

If you want to make it easier for you to distinguish, you can just change the application name for the build you send to specific tracks (internal, closed, production), or you can change the version name for specific ones before generating the Bundle/APK.

```
defaultConfig {
        ...
        versionCode 1 //keep in mind to increase for every new release build
        versionName "1.0-internal" // or "1.0-closed"
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Florent. I just want to keep the application id consistent with flavors since I have internal, closed and open flavors. If we cannot use different application ids for different tracks, then the application id should be the same across all the flavors. I might be able to use versionNameSuffix to distinguish them.